# CSS-only tabs requiring standard rendering of radio buttons and labels within tab

Tags: css

To generate CSS_only tabs, the radio button is sent out of view and the tab label has its particular styling.

```
.tabs input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
.tabs label {
  display: block;
  min-height: 150px;
  padding: 4px 4px;
  [...]
  }
.tabs label:hover {
  background: #E0F8E0;
}
.tabs .tab-content {
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.08em;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  padding: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53px;
  left: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 3px;
  border-top: 3px solid #E0F8E0;
}
.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked ~ [id^="tab-content"] {
  display: block;
}
```

However, within the content of the generated visible div radio buttons and their respective labels need to revert back to a standard mode.

```
<ul class='tabs'>
  <li>
    <input type='radio' name='tabs' id='tab_101' checked />
  <label for='tab_101'>
    <img id='101' name='masteroption %>' src='/masters/101.jpg' />
  </label>
  <div id='tab-content_101' class='tab-content'>
    <input type="radio" id="432432" name="depth" value="432" checked="checked" class='tabs-inner'>
    <label class='tabs-inner-label'>432mm</label>
```

I assigned distinct classes to the inner radio and label tags,

```
.tabs-inner[type='radio'] + label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.tabs-inner-label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #0a0a0a;
}
```

however, the browser developer tool shows that the applied class is still that of the parent not the directly assigned one
[image: not the directly assigned one]

How can different stylings be attributed to these nested items?

Comment: Try adding the !important to enforce your css rule. In general css is applied sequentially so if the distinct classes are defined before the generic classes they won't appear. Also in developer tools in the network tab make sure you have disable cache selected. Last make sure you don't have a typo.

Comment: Please add snipped with [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.tabs .tab-content .tabs-inner-label{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #0a0a0a;
}
```

`!important` is your last resort.

Comment: that does work for the label.  But the positioning of the radio button is still out of sight; worrisome: tools do not even pick up the `tabs-inner` class in its analysis.

Comment: resolved with your same path to solution: `.tabs .tabs-inner[type='radio'] {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;`